# artisan db:seed --database not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, couchbase

I want to seed some data to my database. So far, it all works well with the "normal" database.

Now i want to seed the same data (the same seeder) to another database running. So i try to use the `--database=` command

```
php artisan db:seed --database=cb4test --class=TestDataTableSeeder -v
```

But this will seed the data into the "normal" database, not in the one specified in `cb4test`. What am i doing wrong?

More info:

This a part of my `config/database.php`:

```
    'connections' => [

    'couchbase' => [
        'driver'   => 'couchbase',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 8091),
        'bucket'   => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'n1ql_hosts' => [
            'http://'.env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').':8093'
        ]
    ],

    'cb4test' => [
        'driver'   => 'couchbase',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 8091),
        'bucket'   => env('DB_TEST', 'msg4test'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'n1ql_hosts' => [
            'http://'.env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').':8093'
        ]
    ],
```

In my `.env` i do have an entry for `DB_TEST` pointing to the correct couchbase-bucket (in mysql that would be a mysql-table).

Still, this is not working.
I made a debug line in my `TestDataTableSeeder.php` that gives my the current used DB-Table and this is the one used in the default-connection (named couchbase), not the one used in connection 'cb4test'.

Using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Did you define a correct connection to the cb4test database ?

Comment: Yes, a connection is configured and working. When i make a typo in --database, i will get an error, so laravel looks inside the 'config/database.php' if this connection is there, but it will not use it.

Comment: Can you share sample of seeder classes? May be you define a specific database into seeders

Comment: I have reviewed the seeder with 4 more eyes surrounding me, there is no point where the db connection is overwritten. In the seeder class, i inserted a debug line to print out the current db-table, it points wrong. Is there any point where db connection can change or will be overwritten by default?

Comment: is 'msg4test' name of your default database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we figured out that the source of this problem was related to a bug in the couchbase driver.

Bug fixed, all works well.

Thanks for all the answers trying to help me out :D

Answer (score 2):

Its common misconception, --database specifies the database connection not the name.

So in your **config\database.php** file you need to add up a connection which uses this different database like:

```
'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        ],
```

Then in your **.env**, define three variables for your other db:

```
DB_DATABASE2 = cb4test
DB_USERNAME2 = //username for cb4test
DB_PASSWORD2 = //password for cb4test
```

Then use:

```
php artisan db:seed --database=mysql2 --class=TestDataTableSeeder -v
```

**OR**

Better way of changing database is to change it in seeder itself.
In your: TestDataTableSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;//at top

//then inside function:
DB::disconnect('mysql');
config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => env('DB_DATABASE2','')]);
config(['database.connections.mysql.username' => env('DB_USERNAME','')]);
config(['database.connections.mysql.password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2','')]);
```

Of course you will need those three variables of **.env** file intact.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already done all those things (specially the connection), but this is the point where i came to ask here on SO. I will not work and i have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: is 'msg4test' name of your default database?